# Edit text value is not updated in list view

Tags: android, xml, list, view, adapter

I have custom adapter to show my values in list view (fetched from server and parsed using XML).

the list view row will have  text box and edit text. 
my problem is,

if i want to edit the edit text values and scroll list view, its repeating and also cannot able to update each row in list view after lift from edit text focus.

1. How to update each Row edit text?
2. How to avoid repeat cell values while scrolling?

Below is the code:

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = null;
    final int i = position;

    final ViewHolder holder;

    final RowItem rowItem = (RowItem)getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_edit,  parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.commodityName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commodityName);
        holder.id=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.vendorId);
        holder.unitValue=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.unitValue);
        holder.price=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceValue);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    holder.commodityName.setText(rowItem .getCommodityName());
    holder.price.setText(rowItem.getPrice());
    holder.unitValue.setText(rowItem .getQuantity());
    holder.id.setText(rowItem.getId());

    holder.price.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){


                final EditText Caption = (EditText)v;
                String value = Caption.getText().toString();
                final  int primaryId=v.getId();
                filteredList.get(primaryId).setPrice(value);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else
            {

                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                String value = Caption.getText().toString();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using setOnFocusChangeListener

Comment: while changing from one edit text another edit text, to update the list view..

Comment: For updating list view when moving from one edit text to another edit text in list view

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `notifyDataSetChanged();` in else part too

Try this

```
else
        {

            final int position = v.getId();
            final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
            String value = Caption.getText().toString();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: its not updating the list view. after editing needed edittext fields, when i click ok button,it takes old list only.

Comment: its not updating the list view. after editing needed edittext fields, when i click ok button,it takes old list only.

Comment: its not udating list view. after editing needed edit text fields,when i click ok button, it takes old list data only.  pls help

Comment: <EditText
          android:id="@+id/priceValue"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:maxLength="7"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:inputType="numberDecimal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commodityName"
          android:textColor="#264861"
          >
 category_edit edit-- editText field.

Comment: r u trying to do a filter based on the search keyword ??

Comment: No.. want to update the edit text values of each row and submit to server.

Comment: My problem is, in list view row, after editing a edittext value, then scroll down and going up means , old value only still there.

Comment: then y dont u user holder.price.setText("");. it will clear your edittext

Comment: @omyjeebr.in (!hasfocus) ,when i lift from edittext and going to another edit text in another row, the value is there properly. but scrolling only makes problem.it sets old value. am not much aware of repeat cell process.. pls guide me

Answer (score -1):

In your adapter class override these two methods, it will prevent list item value to repeate while scrolling

```
  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         return position;
  }
```

Comment: Ok. @pokerface when i get id (v.getId) and set the value, it gives Indexoutof boudexception. id value is 21.......2333 so on.  this line gives error. filteredList.get(primaryId).setPrice(value);

Comment: @rahul sharma, even after,its not solved. after editing a edittext value, then scroll down and going up means , old value only still there.. how to solve it.?

Comment: ok try this. in getViewType Count() method return 1 insted of getCount()

Comment: @rahul no luck.. in my code, am i using position properly.. Pls tell me.